# How to get started with C++ unit tests

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing

I am just starting with c++ unit testing. I want to create simple tests (without using any framework) using assert commands. How can I start with that?

Should I make different functions for tests and call them in the main in a single file or should I make separate file for each test?

Comment: Please read [ask].  How to structure unit tests is probably going to be Opinion based and asking for links is Off topic.  See if you can ask a more concrete question.

Comment: The answer to this question very much depends on things like how big is each test, how many tests do you have?

Comment: @john I need to test a particular segment of code. For now, I need to create a few tests (5-6) but the number will increase after things are finalized.

Comment: As Marius's answer shows, unit tests are easy.  There's no dark magic behind them.  The various frameworks (my favorite is [Doctest](https://github.com/doctest/doctest) for modern C++, which is lightweight and easy) just make them a little easier.  If you're doing unit tests as a part of TDD, then my only advice is:  **if you don't have code coverage, you've got bubkes**.

Comment: @ManasviGoyal I would say create testing files that are parallel to the source files. If you have a file called `fred.cpp` which has some functions you want to write unit tests for then create a file called `fred_tests.cpp` for those tests. Also putting the tests in a separate file from the code that they are testing ensures that you are only testing the publicly accessible API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use it like `assert(<output-to-test>==<expected-value>)`

```
#include <cassert>
int square(int x){return x*x}
void test1(){
   assert(square(1)==1)
   assert(square(2)==4)
}
void main(){test1();}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's really helpful. Should I just make different functions for multiple tests and call all of them in main?

Comment: I would probably do it that way. If you want to go for a more advanced way you can take a look at gtest.

Comment: Make sure the tests are in a different cpp file compile and run it just for tests. That way i would do it.